# Cycles: pixel problems, not on first frame ... How to solve?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

See here the first rendered image (Cycles engine). You can notice that the background does not look very pixelated at all. This quality is fine:

[image]

However, in my renders (same Cycles engine, same render ... just some frames later), in subsequent frames, the background (and everything else) suddenly becomes very pixelated:

[image]

I hope this question can be answered. I have not found any other answers on this website, because this question does not relate to fireflies, and the render dimensions stay the change.

*@Yohello1's comment* -> Here are my output properties:

[image]

I render the video via my Mac's terminal:

[image]

Comment: Are you putting it directly to a video format or putting onto individual frames?

Comment: @Yohello1 I have now updated the OP to answer your question. Please help.

Comment: It looks like video compression artifact. That's almost impossible to avoid with the codec you use (divx). You can try a more efficient codec like H264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @thibsert implied, it seems to be the video-codec which creates the problems. If you change it to e.g. H.264 the problem is solved.

[image]

Comment: Too add to this I would recommend using a MP4 container instead

Comment: @Yohello1, Why?

Comment: Just because it's more supported (from why I know )